# How to add style for specific words at HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

Could someone help me to write JS function which will take a string(word) as an argument?
And then add an additional style (change color for example) for all these words in the HTML. I don't know where it is located. This "word" can be inside `<div>`, or `<p>` or even `<b`>.

**Example:**

*HTML:*

```
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<div>Hello World!</div>

function Change(string word){
  //change font color to red
}
```

*Call function:*

```
Change("Hello")
```

*Result:*

All of the "*Hello*" words in the HTML have red font color.

*By the way, is it possible to write something like this?*

Comment: Hi, the basic problem here is how are you defining a 'word'? Is it any occurrence of the string that has non alphabetic characters before and after it? There's a danger that you're getting answers which just change any occurrence of the given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the best solution.** It works fine at any html, just call `matchText("text","black","red");`

```
function replaceInElement(element, find, replace) {
    for (let i= element.childNodes.length; i-->0;) { 
        let child= element.childNodes[i];
        
        if (child.nodeType==1) { 
            let tag= child.nodeName.toLowerCase();  
            if (tag!='style' && tag!='script') 
                replaceInElement(child, find, replace); 
        } else if (child.nodeType==3) { 
            replaceInText(child, find, replace);
        }
    }
}
function replaceInText(text, find, replace) {
    let match; 
    let matches= [];
    
    while (match= find.exec(text.data)){ 
        matches.push(match);
    }
    
    console.log(matches);
    for (let i= matches.length; i-->0;) {
        match = matches[i];

        text.splitText(match.index); 
        text.nextSibling.splitText(match[0].length);

        text.parentNode.replaceChild(replace(match), text.nextSibling); 
    }
}

let matchText = (word, backColor, textColor) => {
    let regexp = new RegExp(`\\b(${word})\\b`, 'gmi');

    replaceInElement(document.body, regexp, function(match) { 

        var elem= document.createElement('span'); 
        elem.style.backgroundColor = backColor;
        elem.style.color = textColor;

        elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
        return elem;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that will find the word and replace it with a `<span class='red'> word </span>`. I have set upa class called 'red' with the style. This is very rudimentary, but works for simple applications. There are explanations in the comments below

```js
function Change(word) {
  //find all html elements on the page inside the body tag
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
  // get our replacement ready
  let span = "<span class='red'>" + word + "</span>";
  //loop through all the elements
  for (let x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    // for each element, 'split' by the word we're looking for, then 'join' it back with the replacement
    elems[x].innerHTML = elems[x].innerHTML.split(word).join(span);
  }
}

Change('Hello');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS is made for styling. Use JS to add the class to your HTML element.

**The Function:**

Pass the **string** to search for and the **selector/s** to search, in my case I am searching all tags in the DOM and returning an array `[...document.getElementsByTagName('*')]`.

We define an ***array*** to hold the *non-restricted* elements we want to search and another that holds the *restricted* tags we want to skip. We then loop the `output` array with `!restricted.includes(tag.nodeName.toLowerCase()`, this checks to see if our ***restricted*** array ***does not include*** an element from our DOM query. For the elements that return ***true***, we push them into our `output` array --> `output.push(tag)`

Once we have our `output` array filled with the tags we want to search, we search the tag for our ***string*** --> `tag.innerText.includes(string)` and **VERY IMPORTANT:** `!(tag.textContent.match(/\n/g)||[]).length` will make sure it is the right child node, if this returns ***true***, we replace the tags `innerHTML` and simply wrap our string with ***span*** tags that now contain a class that is styled as we want it to be styled -->

```
tag.innerHTML = tag.innerText.replace(string, `<span class="red">${string}</span>`)
```

```js
const els = [...document.getElementsByTagName('*')]
const string = "Hello"

function Change(string, els) {
  const restricted = ['html', 'body', 'head', 'style', 'meta', 'script']
  const output = []
  els.forEach(tag => !restricted.includes(tag.nodeName.toLowerCase()) ? output.push(tag) : null)
  output.forEach(tag => tag.innerText.includes(string) && !(tag.textContent.match(/\n/g) || []).length ? tag.innerHTML = tag.innerText.replace(string, `<span class="red">${string}</span>`) : null)
}

Change(string, els)
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<div>Hello World...</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello World.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>
  <a href="#">Hello <span>World</span></a>
</p>

<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Hello</th><th>World</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>World</td><td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tag is not defined

Comment: What tag is not defined?

Comment: @bodkia22 Tag is implicitly defined by the forEach method, array => element (tag). Each element within the array is defined as the given elements name inside the forEach parenthesis, in my example I used the word `tag`. Otherwise JS would throw an error in the console. Did you run the snippit?

Comment: This is the best variant ever! Because it doesn't affect attributes.

Comment: Can I put els to the script?
function Change(string) {
const els = [...document.getElementsByTagName('*')]......

Comment: Why does this script break bbc.com HTML?

Comment: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined, when I tested this script in the bbc.com console(((. Why does this script break bbc.com HTML?

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question? I am not sure how it is ***breaking*** maybe you could explain in a bit more detail. There may be more tags you need to add to your restricted array. console.log the elements that `els = [...document.getElementsByTagName('*')]` is giving you and take a look at the values there to see if you need to accommodate a tag that you do not wish to affect.

Comment: Yeah, there were a lot of tags in els. Maybe it would be good to add some non-restricted tags at the start of the function.

Comment: Yea if you look closely at the function there is this line... `const restricted = ['html', 'body', 'head', 'style', 'meta', 'script']`, you can add any other restricted tags to that array there, just make sure they are seperated with a coma and have quotes around them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really basic example. Note that while this is case insensitive, it will replace all occurrences with whatever case you provide. For example, in the block below I put in `"Hello"`, which sets the one occurrence of `hello` to `Hello`. You could of course remove the `i` in the regex's flags to make it case sensitive again, but you'd have to run the function twice with both cases to highlight both instances.

```js
function color(str, color)
{
  var rx = new RegExp(str, "ig");
  var replaced = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll(rx, "<span style='color:"+color+"'>"+str+"</span>");
  document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
}

color("Hello", "red");
```

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
<p>This block contains the word "hello."</p>
```

Comment: This has no safeguard and would breaks `<body>` or `<section>`, etc.